# Scrapy - item attribute not found

Tags: python, scrapy, libxml2

I am writing a spider which needs to have an item defined like so:

```
import scrapy

    class getInfoItem(scrapy.Item):
        description = scrapy.Field()
        rating = scrapy.Field()
        image = scrapy.Field()
        console = scrapy.Field()
        pass
```

When I try and run the spider, it throws an error on the line of the class declaration, saying that scrapy has no attribute called Item, or to be specific :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Item'
```

I read that this might be because there is some sort of circular dependency somewhere but I am not sure what to do.

Edit: folder directory:

```
getInfo/
    scrapy.cfg
    getInfo/
    __init__.py
    __init__.pyc
    items.py
    items.pyc
    pipelines.pyc
    settings.py
    settings.pyc
    spider/
        getInfo_spider.py
        getInfo_spider.pyc
        __init__.py
        __init.pyc
```

Comment: Can you list the files under your current directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your version of Scrapy, `Item` and `Field` may be found in `scrapy.item`, but not directly in the `scrapy` module:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class getInfoItem(Item):
    description = Field()
    rating = Field()
    image = Field()
    console = Field()
```

For more information compare the *Items* section of Scrapy's documentation for version [0.22](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.22/topics/items.html) and [0.24](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html).

Comment: Thanks, this nailed it! Can't believe the versions are so different!

Comment: What to do for the spiders?